# Can't get working navigator geolocation min-example on Cordova.x Android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, navigator

I'm trying some simple code that works perfectly on localhost with any navigator, but I can't get it to work on a simple Android app.

Simple geolocation code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            window.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){
                if(navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSucces);
                }else{
                    alert("Geolocation not suported")
                }
            },true);  

            function onSucces(pos){
                alert(pos.coords.latitude + "  " + pos.coords.longitude);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Geolocation</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have these Android permissions added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: you have commented the cordova reference

Comment: ye I know just I put it that way cause you can see the example work's nice at localhost

Comment: please right this code in device ready event

Answer (score -1):

You are using HTML5 geolocation, Try using phonegap geolocation and into device ready event, Follow this [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition)

Comment: I tested yet this phongap code and my code it's a simple version of taht tut. 
I will edit my question cause, i put the exemple of localhost.